# Safety of PDO param bindings

Tags: php, security, pdo

I am using parametrized queries with PDO to retrieve data from a MySQL database with a fairly complicated query. As a part of doing this, I use some code similar to this:

The query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = :id_$id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
```

The param binding:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":id_$id", $id);
```

My understanding is that PDO sanitizes your parametrized input by 'cleaning' the replacement string in the call to bindParam, but my question is:
**Could an attacker exploit a construct like the above (via the value of $id) in order to inject undesirable SQL?**

PDO does a textual replacement on the :id_$id with the sanitized value of $id, so I would *think* that no part of :id_$id (no matter what it ends up being) should end up in the final query, but I would love to get a definite answer!

**Edit**: It looks like I wasn't as clear as I should have been in explaining why I believe this *could* be a safe thing to do. Of course, I don't suggest that this is a *good* way to do things.

The reason I think this could be safe is that PDO (correct me if this is wrong) does a textual replacement of the sanitized bound-param on the replacement text. Intuitively, this should indicate that the replacement text (":id_$id") can be any value, since it will be entirely replaced by PDO when the parameter is placed in the query. Since the parameter replacing involves sanitizing the value of the parameter, while ":id_$id" may be dangerous to execute, "$id" (which is what appears in the final query) should be safe.

That's my reasoning, anyways. I'm not doing anything this dangerous in my code, so this is more of an academic interest.

Comment: This IS vulnerable (think of `$id = ' OR 1=1'`, and see what it _prepares_).

Comment: The tricky part of the question is that your replacement param would become: ":id_ OR 1=1", which (I think) should be replaced in the final text with a sanitized version of " OR 1=1", which would not execute. I can run some more tests myself, but I would rather get an expert opinion from someone who knows the answer (than just assume I have tested all inputs).

Comment: Ah, I see the point, the `bindParam()` will never bind a proper param in case of injection, making the execute error out on 'parameter not defined'. I can indeed personally think of no workable exploit at this time, but expert opinion is: unescaped variables have _no_ place in your prepared string, not even when you cannot think of an exploit at the time, and _certainly_ not when there's no reason for it. Keep in mind only binding a parameter is _no_ string replace: `:id_ OR 1=1` would not be replaced, but would require you to bind a `:id_` param to succeed.

Comment: Can you explain that last part? The more I think about it, the more I am convinced that given the 'bad' input from your first comment, you should see the following: ":id_$id" --php string replace--> ":id_ OR 1=1", which is then replaced (via PDO) by ":id_$id" --php string replace--> ":id_ OR 1=1" --magic pdo escaping--> <something safe>.

Comment: Not every character is valid in a named parameter. Parameters can be given in 2 ways: `?`, or OTOH, `:`, followed by `[a-zA-Z_]`, followed by one or or moe `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. However, this is somewhat database dependant, and MySQL does not even _support_ named parameters, so PDO emulates them. I'd have to delve in the C code to be sure, but `'` or ` ` (space) are _definitely_ not valid.

Comment: @Wrikken, I did some testing and I think you're right. The space in the replacement param appears to break the text matching. If you put something in an answer I'd be happy to mark you as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's vulnerable.

However, using named placeholders is entirely optional. So, you don't have to use them at all:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
```

And, you know, whatever fairly complicated code can be simplified.

Comment: Can you prove that it is vulnerable? I will update my question with a more concrete example as to why I believe it -could- be safe. I found a definitely-safe way to solve my problem, but I would still love an answer to satisfy my academic interest in the problem :)

Comment: Did you notice the very first comment under the question, from Wrikken?

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer. Just use prepared statements, don't concat variables unless you have a **VERY** good reason to do so

Answer (score -1):

pdo does sanitize the input, you can further specify types in the third argument of bindValue/bindParam. I'd avoid using $ as part of your token as it could be interpreted by php if in "":

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = :id;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

this would ensure that if $id is not an int pdo should raise an exception.

Even attempting to inject sql in this manner is escaped.

Comment: Having the $id replaced in the query string is intentional, and exactly what I am asking about.

Comment: understood - it should still be escaped though.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using a closed set of allowed values for $id. I mean:

```
switch ($id) {
  case "value01":
    $param = ":id_01";
    break;

  case "value02":
    $param = ":id_02";
    break;

  default:
    // safe value
    $param = ":id_00";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = $param";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam("$param", $id);
```

Comment: Don't you find it actually spoiling the very idea of prepared statements?

Comment: I have never done things this way and I do not recommend doing that. That was just to try to find a workaround for the user to be able to do what he wants.

Comment: While your example isn't quite what I was trying to accomplish, it is somewhat similar to my actual implementation. Instead of using user-sourced-values for my $id in :id_$id, I used a parallel mapping that I know is safe.